# How do I refund a customer using Stripe Library

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe for handling the payment process,and I come to the point when I have to refund the customers.

So far I am using this code:

```
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "source" => $token,
                "description" => $email)
        );

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'amount' => $amount, // Amount in cents!
            'currency' => $this->currency,
            "description" => $email,
            "customer" => $customer->id
        ));
```

Once this is done, I store customer id to my users table customers. I have the customer stored id and later I wanna refund him, How do I do that?

I know you can refund using this code:

```
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve($charge_id);
    $refund = $charge->refunds->create();
```

My case is a bit different that how do I find the charge_id using customer id, somewhat?

Thanks

Comment: This is not  a development question. This is an API question. Go look at the API documentation.

Comment: @taco I didnt know stackoverflow is not place for different API support libraries too... if you dont consider API development then I dont know what do u consider development nowadays...

Comment: If you haven't stored the charge id (ch_XXX) on your end you can find the charge using https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_charges along with the customer id in the `customer` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            'amount' => $amount, // Amount in cents!
            'currency' => $this->currency,
            "description" => $email,
            "customer" => $customer->id
));
```

Then add this lines :

```
$details = json_decode($charge);
$result = get_object_vars($details);
```

Now you get all the result in $result variable then you find:

```
$charge_id = $result['id'];
```